# Set the radius of one corner of a SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to change the radius of two corners of a SKShapeNode (rect) but I didn't find a working solution. 
I've tried to use a path, and it didn't work. 
Swift 4.2, iOS 12.1.1, Xcode 10.1

```
let shape = SKShapeNode()
shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256), cornerRadius: 64).cgPath
shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
shape.fillColor = UIColor.red
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
shape.lineWidth = 10
addChild(shape)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a function that will allow you to customize each corner radius to whatever size you'd like. You can have 1,2,3 or 4 corners with a radius. If you always just want two corners then I would suggest making a wrapper function so you don't have so many parameters to fill in each time you call it.

```
func CustomRoundRectPath(_ rect:CGRect, _ TLR:CGFloat,_ TRR:CGFloat,_ BLR:CGFloat,_ BRR:CGFloat) -> CGPath {

    let w = rect.width
    let h = rect.height

    //TLP:(TLP)
    let TLP = CGPoint(x: TLR, y: h - TLR)
    let TRP = CGPoint(x: w - TRR, y: h - TRR)
    let BLP = CGPoint(x: BLR, y: BLR)
    let BRP = CGPoint(x: w - BRR, y: BRR)

    //Create path and addComponents
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addArc(center: TLP, radius: TLR, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: TRP.x, y: h))
    path.addArc(center: TRP, radius: TRR, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: BRP.y))
    path.addArc(center: BRP, radius: BRR, startAngle: 0, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: BLP.x, y: 0))
    path.addArc(center: BLP, radius: BLR, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: TLP.y))

    return path
}
```

Comment: Can I do it without centering the rectangle?

Comment: I assumed you wanted it centered. Anyways, I edited the answer so that it doesn't center the rectangle.